# Importing data from Access into Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in an Excel budget worksheet I am working on that pulls an entire table from an Access database. My macro then has a bunch of SUMIFS and formatting functions that organize and format specific data into a separate worksheet. I would prefer that the entire table (21,000 lines of budget data) not be dumped into the Excel worksheet when I only require a few lines of data depending on which "team" I am selecting. Is there any way to specify in my Access data dump that I only want specific lines of data from the table (of 21,000 lines) rather than the entire table? Is there a way to ignore the headers when doing the data dump?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes to both questions. If you specify what method you are using to import the data, perhaps I can give you an example of how to add the select statement and ignore headers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am just going into the Excel > Data tab and clicking on "From Access". I basically created a macro so when I click on a button titled "Load Data" it replicates that process by creating a table in an extra worksheet, then formatting the data in the cell I want it to be in.

Answer (score 0):

If you've recorded a macro doing this, you can simply edit the commandtext to be your select statement. Example below would only pull a single column, ID, from the Templates table, instead of the whole table.

```
Sub MyRecordedMacro
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\meuser\Desktop\database.accdb;Mode=Share Deny " _
    , _
    "Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:En" _
    , _
    ...
    .CommandText = "Select ID From Templates"
    ...
    ...
    End With
```

You can learn how to create an appropriate select statement here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

I don't know how to exclude headers from this type of import. However you could just delete the header row in excel after the import.

Comment: This is the right track, but I need many columns, and a specified number of rows. For example, we have about 1000 different "teams". I want to select all of the rows from 1 "team", which is only about 10 lines of data. From those 10 lines of data I only need about 10 columns of about 25. I also need the headers of each column removed.

Comment: Sounds like your select statement should look something like...
Select col1, col2, col3, ... col10 from [table] where [team] = 'team1'

Comment: You're right Greg. I need it to look something like..    Select January,February,March from My_data_table WHERE facility=facility1 AND team=team1

Comment: Some of my columns also have a space in them, ie: "Year 1". When I use the code Select Year 1 From My_table   ...the code breaks. Won't let me use "" marks either.